# Can't put comments form above list of comments in Rails

Tags: ruby, comments, ruby-on-rails-4

I've seen a few other stackoverflow questions with the same question, but the answers haven't helped...

I have a two-deep nested association. My parent_model has:many child_models which has:many comments

On the Show action for the child_model I'm showing the comments associated with it. If i put the comment form below the loop of comments, then everything works fine. I'd prefer to put the form before the list of comments, so user's dont have to scroll to the bottom to comment. When i do this, i get an error involving the user. I have tried to switch the form from 'build' to 'new' and a few other suggestion's people had, but nothing is working...Here is my child_models show action

```
@collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
@design = @collection.designs.find(params[:id])
```

I have a comments controller as well and here is the create action

```
@collection = Collection.find(params[:collection_id])
@design = @collection.designs.find(params[:design_id])
@comment = @design.comments.create(comment_params)
@comment.user = current_user
@comment.save
```

Can anyone figure out how to solve this problem? Thank you in advance for taking the time.

Comment: Can you please provide the error?

Comment: I have an if then in the view to separate between two charactertics of users...the if/then works but when i put the form above the loop the error says undefined method 'role'...role is an attribute of users..

Comment: You should probably share the view code…you've already pointed out that's where the problem is.